# I got stuck on iteration, it shows result perfect but when I render on the component level on load it loads on the same field but last object on

Tags: javascript, arrays, next.js, use-state

I got stuck in rendering component level on load.
When I click edit and call edit function, it loads data properly in console and show all objects but it doesn't render on the page level.

Here is my code:

```
const handleEdit = async () => {
    const { searchBrand } = await searchBrandAPI({ id });
    searchBrand[0].translations.forEach(arrVal => {
        console.log(arrVal, 'arrVal');
        setDynamicValues([ ...dynamicValues, {
                transLanguage: { label: arrVal.language, value: arrVal.languauge },
                transName: arrVal.name,
                transIsActive: { label: formatFirstCharUpperCase(arrVal.isActive, String), value: arrVal.isActive },
        }]);
    }); 
    const strIsActive = { label: formatFirstCharUpperCase(searchBrand[0].isActive, String), value: searchBrand[0].isActive }
    setValues({ name: searchBrand[0].name, isActive: strIsActive })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it this way.

```
const handleEdit = async () => {
    const { searchBrand } = await searchBrandAPI({ id });
    const transData = [];
    searchBrand[0].translations.forEach(arrVal => {
        transData.push({
            transLanguage: { label: arrVal.language, value: arrVal.languauge },
            transName: arrVal.name,
            transIsActive: { label: formatFirstCharUpperCase(arrVal.isActive, String), value: arrVal.isActive },
        });
    });
    setDynamicValues(transData);
    const strIsActive = { label: formatFirstCharUpperCase(searchBrand[0].isActive, String), value: searchBrand[0].isActive }
    setValues({ name: searchBrand[0].name, isActive: strIsActive })
}
```

Is this the right way? because I tried memo as well as callback but same thing was showing like last record only even on console it was showing perfect!
Please confirm, if I did this in a right way or is there any other shortest way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

To guarantee, that you get the latest value of the `state`, you need to use `useState` `callback` function to get the previous value.

```
const handleEdit = async () => {
  const { searchBrand } = await searchBrandAPI({ id });
  searchBrand[0].translations.forEach(arrVal => {
    console.log(arrVal, 'arrVal');
    setDynamicValues(prev => [ ...prev, {
      transLanguage: {
        label: arrVal.language,
        value: arrVal.languauge
      },
      transName: arrVal.name,
      transIsActive: {
        label: formatFirstCharUpperCase(arrVal.isActive, String),
        value: arrVal.isActive
      },
    }]);
  }); 
  const strIsActive = {
    label: formatFirstCharUpperCase(searchBrand[0].isActive, String),
    value: searchBrand[0].isActive
  }
  setValues({ name: searchBrand[0].name, isActive: strIsActive })
}
```

As `setState` is an async operation, so the value of `dynamicValues` doesn't update immediately when you call `setDynamicValues`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried but it's result same as I used spread operator. It's showing last result at the end nor showing all values in different fields. I am using add and remove fields dynamically component.